# Can the MailSettingsSectionGroup parser be used outside an application configuration file?

Tags: c#, configuration, smtp

.NET provides a nice, elegant way to define SMTP configuration in an application configuration file:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="somewhere@example.com">
      <network host="mySmtpServer" ...more authentication data... />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

[SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses this configuration automatically, and, heck, I can even [access these setting programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/625262/87698), if I need to:

```
var mailSettings = (MailSettingsSectionGroup)myAppConfig.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");

// now I can access mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host, etc.
```

And now to something completely different:

It happens that I have an *external* XML configuration file (*not* app.config or web.config), and I need to store SMTP configuration data there, so I thought I'd just use the same format that .NET uses. After all, some very smart people put a lot of thought into that, so why reinvent the wheel?

Now, finally (thanks for your patience), we get to the question:

**Can I reuse the MailSettingsSectionGroup parser?**

I was hoping that there is some public `MailSettingsSectionGroup.Parse(myXElement)`  method or some `new MailSettingsSectionGroup(myXElement)` constructor, but I could not find one. Is the parser publicly available or is it hidden in some internal `System.Configuration` class that I cannot reuse?