# How to check whether an SMTP mailbox is available

Tags: asp.net, email, c#-4.0, sendmail

I want to check whether an SMTP mailbox is available for a given username and password. I am using the `SmtpClient.Send` method to send the email, but before sending it I want to check the whether the credentials provided are correct and also to check whether the SMTP server is valid.

How can I do this from C#?

Comment: Just to make sure I understood, you want to check not if the recipient's mailbox is available, but if the sender's username and password are valid on that SMTP server?

Comment: see a old link.I think it helps you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372742/can-i-test-smtpclient-before-calling-client-send

Comment: yes I want check sender's username and password are valid on that SMTP server.

Comment: Please can anybody tell me how to check the configured sender's SMTP server name, username and password are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the API provides the equivalent of an "is valid" type of query. However, when you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx), it states that an `SmtpException` will be thrown if the send fails; two of the reasons for failure include what you were looking for

- invalid server (i.e. you couldn't connect with the SMTP protocol)
- authentication failed (i.e. invalid username and password)

So handling that exception and inspecting it for whether the failure was indeed due to an authentication failure or a server connection failure should provide you with what you need.

Comment: thanks kit really helpful..simply wasting the time to check SMTP mailbox is available or not.